# How to make a numbered list which start numbering from number of title?

Tags: lists, enumerate

I need to make like this:
[image]

As seen in the picture, the number of each new title also increases by one.

I found a similar example, but this is slightly different:
[stackoverflow.com/q/2007627](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2007627)

Comment: Using the `enumitem` package, I would say `\begin{enumerate}[label={\thesection.\alph*,]}`, or more convenient, with `\setlist[enumerate,2]{label*={\alph*.}}` for the 2nd level

Comment: It should have been `\begin{enumerate}[label={\thesection.\arabic*,}]`, of course, using `\arabic*` instead of `\alph`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution:

```
\renewcommand\thesection{\arabic{section}} % Optional. Removing the chapter number from the section number.

\section{First title} 
\begin{enumerate}[label={\thesection.\arabic*.}]
    \item First topic:
    \begin{enumerate}[label*=\arabic*.]
        \item First Subtopic;
        \item Second Subtopic;
        \item Third Subtopic.
    \end{enumerate}
    \item Second topic:
    \begin{enumerate}[label*=\arabic*.]
        \item First Subtopic;
        \item Second Subtopic;
        \item Third Subtopic.
    \end{enumerate}
\end{enumerate}

\section{Second title}  
\begin{enumerate}[label={\thesection.\arabic*.}]
    \item First topic:
    \begin{enumerate}[label*=\arabic*.]
        \item First Subtopic;
        \item Second Subtopic;
        \item Third Subtopic.
    \end{enumerate}
    \item Second topic:
    \begin{enumerate}[label*=\arabic*.]
        \item First Subtopic;
        \item Second Subtopic;
        \item Third Subtopic.
    \end{enumerate}
\end{enumerate}
```